# Masking a Register Using Its Pointer - AVR Ports

Tags: c++, pointers, avr, bitmask, atmega

I'm programming a Simon Says game with a microprocessor (atmega32) using some LEDs and buttons. I am trying to store the pointers to a PORT register in an array, which a function will use to mask the register (to turn the pins on to light the LED) depending on which button is pressed.

Something along the lines of

```
*arrayOfPointers[1] |= 1 << mask;
```

But I don't think this is working, and I think it is because I don't completely understand how masking or pointers work.

How do I mask a register, when I have the pointer to this register stored in an array of pointers? Please note I am a beginner/novice, so please explain like I'm stupid.

Here is a simplified sample of the relevant code:

```cpp
volatile uint8_t *portActivate[numberOfButtons]; //stores pointers to the PORT register
unsigned char pinActivate[numberOfButtons];  //stores the pin I want to turn on

//activateOnPress populates 2 arrays that stores the PORT and PIN corresponding to each button. (index 0 is for button 0, index 1 is for button 1, etc.)
//this will be used to tell the program which PORT and PIN to activate (output a voltage) when that button is pressed.
void activateOnPress(unsigned int buttonNumber, volatile uint8_t *activatePort, unsigned char activatePin){
    *portActivate[buttonNumber] = *activatePort;    //store the pointer to PORT register in an array
    pinActivate[buttonNumber] = activatePin;    //store the pin to be turned on at that port
}

//buttonListen will see if the specified button has been pressed (voltage on pin is 0)
//if it has, it will output a voltage to the associated pin given by my 2 arrays by masking the register pointed to by the *portActivate array.
void buttonListen(unsigned int buttonNumber,unsigned char buttonPort, unsigned char buttonPin){
    if(bit_is_clear(buttonPort, buttonPin)){    //bit_is_clear means the pin is showing 0V  
        *portActivate[buttonNumber] |= 1 << pinActivate[buttonIndex];  //this is the part thats not working!!!!
    }
}

int main(void){
    activateOnPress(1, &PORTB, PIN0);  //associate button 1 to PORT B, PIN 0, which I want to activate (output 5V) when this button is pressed

    while(1){
        buttonListen(1, PORTA, PIN1); //listen to PORT A, PIN 1. If it's pressed, then output a voltage to the port and pin associated with button 1.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: _"But I don't think this is working, "_ What makes you think so? The usual way of _masking_ should look like `*arrayOfPointers[1] &= mask;` though.

Comment: Because the LED is not lighting up, but when I do it directly using        PORTB |= 1 << PIN1 then it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written many device drivers over the years.  So, I think I see [at least one of] your problems.

I had to do some style cleanup to eliminate long sidebar comments.  Most style guides recommend no wider than 80.  It makes the code hard to read.  I had to do this so I could understand your logic.

Also, you had two parallel arrays, indexed by button number.  I merged these into a struct, which associates the data better.

Anyway, here's the cleaned up code, with the bug fix (Hint: `#if`):

```
struct portpin {
    // stores pointers to the PORT register
    volatile uint8_t *portActivate;

    // stores the pin I want to turn on
    unsigned char pinActivate;
};
typedef struct portpin portpin_t;

portpin_t portlist[numberOfButtons];

// activateOnPress populates 2 arrays that stores the PORT and PIN corresponding
// to each button. (index 0 is for button 0, index 1 is for button 1, etc.)
// this will be used to tell the program which PORT and PIN to activate (output
// a voltage) when that button is pressed.
void
activateOnPress(unsigned int butno,volatile uint8_t *activatePort,
    unsigned char activatePin)
{
    portpin_t *port;

    port = &portlist[butno];

    // store the pointer to PORT register in an array
#if 0
    *port->portActivate = *activatePort;  // your code
#else
    port->portActivate = activatePort;  // fixed code
#endif

    // store the pin to be turned on at that port
    port->pinActivate = activatePin;
}

// buttonListen will see if the specified button has been pressed (voltage on
// pin is 0) if it has, it will output a voltage to the associated pin given by
// my 2 arrays by masking the register pointed to by the *portActivate array.
void
buttonListen(unsigned int butno,unsigned char buttonPort,
    unsigned char buttonPin)
{
    portpin_t *port;

    port = &portlist[butno];

    // bit_is_clear means the pin is showing 0V  
    if (bit_is_clear(buttonPort, buttonPin)) {
        // this is the part thats not working!!!!
        *port->portActivate |= 1 << port->pinActivate;
    }
}

int
main(void)
{

    // associate button 1 to PORT B, PIN 0, which I want to activate (output 5V)
    // when this button is pressed
    activateOnPress(1, &PORTB, PIN0);

    // listen to PORT A, PIN 1. If it's pressed, then output a voltage to the
    // port and pin associated with button 1.
    while (1)
        buttonListen(1, PORTA, PIN1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to write that. Looks like I have a lot of research to do. If you were to summarize what you changed, what would you say the main problem (or two) was?

Comment: Simple.  Bug manifested itself in buttonListen, but the root cause was in activateOnPress.  There, you had _*portActivate[buttonNumber] = *activatePort_ and you wanted _portActivate[buttonNumber] = activatePort_.  In other words, you wanted portActivate[i] to contain the port address, but what you were giving it was the contents of the port, not the address of the port (e.g. you were derefing the pointer, but that comes later in buttonListen).

Comment: Worse yet, because you were doing *portActivate[i] = ... instead of portActivate[i] =, and portActivate[i] had not _yet_ been assigned to, the actual place in memory where the data went is arbitrary/undefined.  You're quite lucky you didn't get a segmentation fault doing that.  The probable place it went was memory address 0x00000000.  On an x86, that would generate an exception.  On some other systems, it trashes interrupt vectors, and other systems it would be harmless--YMMV